# Call a function in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, global-asax

Is it possible to call a function in Global.asax from a class libray project which is present in the same solution?

Comment: Yes. Are you running into any problem?

Comment: I need to get the appsettings value from web.config to a class library project under the same solution. So i thought of writing a function in global.asax and getting the same..

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Where exactly need you help? But's it easier to access the app settings directly from you class library project. I don't see no need to go via Global.asax.

Comment: can you tell me how can i get the appsetting value from my class library project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the app settings in web.config from your code, just add the following code:

```
using System.Configuration;

...

string appVersion = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppVersion"];
```

It assumes, your web.config contains the following section:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="AppVersion" value="1.0.1"/>
</appSettings>
```

If the `System.Configuration` namespace is not known, then you have to add a reference to `System.Configuration`.

Comment: Thanks Codo... i didnt try this.. I thought it is not possible to get appsetting value from an another project.... It works ... Thanks again